# Finding the right conditions for a sequence to satisfy convergence in distribution then convergence in probability then convergence almost surely

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

I couldn't solve this exercice so I could use some help. It goes like this : 
Let $(X_n)_{n \in\Bbb N^*}$ be a sequence of real independent random variable defined in some probability space. Let $F_{X_n}$ be the cumulutive distribution function such that
$$F_{X_n}=\begin{cases}
1 & \quad   x > 1\\
a_n+(1-a_n)x^n & \quad x \in[0,1] \\ 
0 & \quad  x <0
\end{cases}$$

$a_n\in [0,1] $

**Question** :
Find the right conditions for $a_n$ to have :

1/ Convergence in distribution.

2/ Convergence in probability.

3/Almost sure convergence.

( note that the questions are seperated so it needs to be solved one at a time ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1/ [Convergence in distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_distribution)**: We have $X_n$ converges in distribution iff $F_{X_n}(x)$ converges for all $x$.

For $x \in [0,1)$, as $a_n \in [0,1]$ then $(1-a_n)x^n \xrightarrow{n \to +\infty} 0 $, so
$F(x)$ converges for $x \in [0,1)$ iff the sequence $a_n$ converges to $a$. And because $F_{X_n}(x) \in [0,1]$ then $a \in [0,1]$.

We check this condition $a \in [0,1]$. Indeed, with this condition, $X_n$ converges to the distribution $$X with ( $P(X=0) = a$ and $P(X=1) = 1-a$)

Hence, $X_n$ converges in distribution if and only if the sequence $a_n$ converges to $a \in [0,1]$.

**2/ [Convergence in probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_probability)**:

As [the convergence in probability implies the convergence in distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Properties_2), then a necessary condition of the convergence in probability is the sequence $a_n$ converges to $a \in [0,1]$. And so, $X_n$ converges to $X$ with ($P(X=0) = a$ and $P(X=1) = 1-a$).

It suffices to verify if this condition is sufficient. We need

$$P(|X_n-X| \ge \epsilon) \xrightarrow{n \to +\infty} 0 $$

We have
\begin{align}
P(|X_n-X| \ge \epsilon) & = P(\{|X_n-X| \ge \epsilon \} \cap \{ X = 0\}) +P(\{|X_n-X| \ge \epsilon \} \cap \{ X = 1\}) \\
&= P(X=0)P(X_n \ge \epsilon ) +P(X=1)P( 1-X_n \ge \epsilon ) \\
&= a(1-F_{X_n}(\epsilon)) +(1-a)F_{X_n}(1-\epsilon) \\
&= a(1-a_n-(1-a_n)\epsilon^n) +(1-a)(a_n + (1-a_n)(1-\epsilon)^n) \tag{1}
\end{align}
Then
$$P(|X_n-X| \ge \epsilon) \xrightarrow{n \to +\infty} a(1-a) + (1-a)a = 2a(1-a)$$

By consequence, we can conclude that the $X_n$ converges in probability if and only if the sequence $a_n$ converges to $a = 0$ or $a=1$. And $X_n$ converges to the constant $X = 1-a$.

**3/ Convergence almost sure**:

As [the convergence almost sure implies the convergence in probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Properties_3) then a necessary condition for the almost sure convergence is the sequence $a_n$ converges to $a = 0$ or $a = 1$ .

We need to check if this condition is sufficient by using the [Borel-Cantelli Lemma](https://www.math.mcgill.ca/dstephens/OldCourses/556-2006/Math556-BorelCantelli.pdf). Let's denote
$$A_n(\epsilon) = \{ \omega: |X_n(\omega) - 0| > \epsilon\} $$

From $(1)$, we have

- If $a = 0$: $$P(A_n(\epsilon)) = a_n + (1-a_n)(1-\epsilon)^n$$ $$\implies \sum_{n=1}^N P(A_n(\epsilon)) =\sum_{n=1}^N a_n + \sum_{n=1}^N (1-a_n)(1-\epsilon)^n $$ We notice that if the sequence $a_n$ converges then $\sum_{n=1}^N (1-a_n)(1-\epsilon)^n < +\infty$, then $\sum_{n=1}^N P(A_n(\epsilon)) <+\infty$ if and only if $$\sum_{n=1}^N a_n<+\infty \tag{2}$$
- If $a = 1$: $$P(A_n(\epsilon)) = (1-a_n)(1-\epsilon^n)$$ $$ \implies \sum_{n=1}^N P(A_n(\epsilon)) = \sum_{n=1}^N (1-a_n)+  \sum_{n=1}^N (1-a_n)\epsilon^n $$ As $X_n$ independent, by applying the Borel-Cantelli Lemma (part b), if the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} (1-a_n) = \infty$ then $X_n$ can't converge to $X = 0$. Hence, $\sum_{n=1}^N P(A_n(\epsilon)) <+\infty$ if and only if
  $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} (1-a_n) < +\infty \tag{3}$$  (it's evident that $\sum_{n=1}^N (1-a_n)\epsilon^n <+\infty$)

And by applying the Borel-Cantelli Lemma (part a), we have $(2)$ and $(3)$ are also the sufficient condition for the almost sure convergence.

By consequence, $X_n$ converges almost surely if and only if one of these conditions occurs $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} (1-a_n) < +\infty$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} a_n < +\infty$$

Comment: For 2/, $P(|X_n-X|\ge \epsilon)\to 2a(1-a)$.

Comment: @JGWang You are right.  Thank you!

Comment: 2/  could be deduced from Kolmogorov 0-1 law simply also.

Comment: @JGWang I don't how 2/ could be deduced from Kolmogorov 0-1 law. Could you give any idea of proof using this?

Comment: From Kolmogorov's 0-1 Law, $X$ is degenerated, i.e. there exists a $c$, $P(X=c)=1$.

Comment: @JGWang It seems to me that you used Kolmogorov's 0-1 Law for *3/* (convergence a.s) and not *2/* (convergence in probability). And about 3/, the Kolmogorov's 0-1 Law  can only say that the sequence $X_n$ converges to a constant $c$ but can't determine the value of $c$

Comment: If $ X_n\overset{pr}{\longrightarrow}X $, then there exists a supsequence of independent
r.v's $ \{X_{n_k},k\ge 1\}$ such that,  $ X_{n_k}\overset{a.s.}{\longrightarrow}X $. 
Hence $ X\in\bigcap\limits_{k\ge 1}\sigma(X_{n_j},j\ge k) $,
therefore, $ X $ is degenerated by Kolmogorov's 0-1 law.

Comment: @JGWang Yes, but what you proved is for the part *3/ Almost sure convergence* (and not the part *2/*) as I remarked in the comment above. Besides, this theorem can't say anything about the value of $c$ nor the condition for the almost sure convergence.

Comment: Here is a proof(based on the part 1/) of necessary condition of convergence in probiability:
If $ X_n\overset{pr}{\longrightarrow}X $,   then there exists a supsequence of independent
r.v's $ \{X_{n_k},k\ge 1\}$ such that,  $ X_{n_k}\overset{a.s.}{\longrightarrow}X $. 
Hence $ X\in\bigcap\limits_{k\ge 1}\sigma(X_{n_j},j\ge k)=\overline{\{\emptyset,\Omega\}}$ (Kolmogorov's 0-1 law), i.e. there exists a constant $ c $ such that, $ \mathsf{P}(X=c)=1 $. Furthermore, $ c=0 $ or $ 1 $ using 1/ .

Comment: @Kurt.W.X Thank you, indeed we could have $\sum_k a_k <+\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

1/ Suppose that $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$. Then $F_{X_n}$ converges almost everywhere to $F_X$. In particular there exist $x,y\in(0,1)$, $x\neq y$ such that the sequences $x_n=a_n+(1-a_n)x$ and $y_n=a_n+(1-a_n)y$ converge. Since $a_n=(yx_n-xy_n)/(y-x)$ we deduce that $a_n$ must converge to some $a\in\mathbb R$. Since $a_n\in[0,1]$ we even have $a\in[0,1]$.

Conversely suppose that $a_n$ converges to some $a\in[0,1]$. Then $F_{X_n}$ converges everywhere to the map $F$ defined by $F(x)=0$ if $x<0$, $F(x)=1$ if $x>1$ and $F(x)=a+(1-a)x^n$ if $x\in[0,1]$. It is clear that $F$ is nondecreasing from $0$ to $1$ and right-continuous. Therefore there exists a random variable $X$ whose $F$ is the distribution function (take $X=F^{-1}(U)$ where $F^{-1}$ is the left pseudo-inverse of $F$ and $U$ uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$). Since $F_{X_n}$ converges on $\mathbb R$ to $F_X$ we deduce that $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$.

We deduce that there is convergence is distribution iff $a_n$ is convergent.

3/ Suppose that $X_n$ converges almost surely to $X$. According to 1/, we saw that $a_n$ converges to $a\in[0,1]$ and $F_{X_n}$ converges to $F_X$ almost everywhere. Since $X_n$, $n\in\mathbb N^*$ are independent, it is well known that the almost sure limit $X$ is almost surely constant, see for instance [Independence is preserved under taking almost sure limits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290193/independence-is-preserved-under-taking-almost-sure-limits) applied with $Y_n=X_{n+1}$. So $X$ is almost surely constant. In other words, there exists $y\in[0,1]$ such that $F_X(y-)=0$ and $F_X(y)=1$. Since $F_X(y)=a+(1-a)x^n$ for all $x\in[0,1]$, this can only happen if $a=1$, in which case $X$ is almost surely constant equal to $0$.

Conversely, suppose that $a_n$ converges to $1$. Let $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$. For all $n\in\mathbb N^*$ we have $\mathbb P(X_n>\varepsilon)=1-F_{X_n}(\varepsilon)=1-a_n-(1-a_n)\varepsilon^n=(1-a_n)(1-\varepsilon^n)$. Therefore $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N^*}\mathbb P(X_n>\varepsilon)$ converges iff $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N^*}(1-a_n)$ converges.

If $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N^*}(1-a_n)$ converges, then by the Borel-Cantelli lemma, $\mathbb P(\bigcap_{N\in\mathbb N^*}\bigcup_{n\ge N}\{X_n>\varepsilon\})=0$. Equivalently, we have almost surely $\bigcup_{N\in\mathbb N^*}\bigcap_{n\ge N}\{X_n\le\varepsilon\}$. By taking for instance $\varepsilon=1/p$, this shows that almost surely, for all $p\in\mathbb N^*$, there exists $N\in\mathbb N^*$ such that for all $n\ge N$, $X_n\le1/p$, hence $X_n$ converges almost surely to $0$.

If $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N^*}(1-a_n)$ does not converge, then by the Borel-Cantelli lemma again, $\mathbb P(\bigcap_{N\in\mathbb N^*}\bigcup_{n\ge N}\{X_n>\varepsilon\})=1$. We deduce that almost surely, for all $N\in\mathbb N^*$ there exists $n\ge N$ such that $X_n>\varepsilon$, which contradicts that $X_n$ converges almost surely to $0$.

We deduce that there is almost sure convergence iff $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N^*}(1-a_n)$ converges.

2/ Suppose that $X_n$ converges in probability. It is well known that convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution, and also almost sure convergence of a subsequence. From 1/ we deduce that $a_n$ converges to some $a\in[0,1]$, and from 2/ we deduce that there exists a subsequence of $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N^*}$ which converges to $1$, hence $a=1$ and $a_n$ converges to $1$.

Conversely, suppose that $a_n$ converges to $1$. From 1/ we deduce that $X_n$ converges in distribution to a variable which is almost surely constant to $0$. It is well known that convergence in distribution implies convergence in probability as soon as the limit is almost surely constant. Hence $X_n$ converges in probability.

We deduce that there is convergence in probability iff $a_n$ converges to $1$.